# Intercept and then Pass on touch events to the underlying app

Tags: android, events, touch, overlay

I know this type of question is already asked and it is well known that we can't pass on touch events to underlying apps with ICS or newer versions of android.

But I wonder how home launcher app is able to pass on touch events to live wallpapers app.I mean both apps can use all the touch events normally.

Example : Galaxy s3 live wallpaper.

Is there any special way given for launchers to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any special way given for launchers to do that?

No, because they are not two apps. The home screen has a launcher, and the home screen has live wallpaper.